# First time login to Ubuntu Core on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu-core

I just installed VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.10 with an intent to install Ubuntu Core.  The installation was successful and everything has worked out fine until I need to login to Ubuntu Core for the first time.

Essentially I do not have the login or password which is asked for at startup.  This is a common problem apparently but there are no clear instructions on how to address it.  For some people:

**localhost login: ubuntu**

**password: ubuntu**

works for them just fine but not me.

I have acquired a Ubuntu One account and I have imported my SSH keys.
I have tried every combination of login and pass codes I can think of. I have read all the docs and posts I can find regarding this issue and I have found no solution.

Please be explicit in your response.  Thanks in advance you ridiculously awsome people.

Comment: There is **no** local login in Ubuntu Core 16 by default; it's SSH only (you can set a password once you login if you want). You should have encountered the first boot configuration wizard, where you setup network and entered the email address associated with your SSO account. At that time, did your SSO account have SSH keys associated with it?

Comment: I believe so.  Are you referring to the SSH Keys which were imported on The Ubuntu One page?  In the case that I did everything correctly what is the format for logging in.  When I try to log in using the 
ssh <user>@<address>

the port 22 connection times out.